# Treehouse Construction

Tags: wood, deck, decking, treehouse

I want to run a treehouse design idea by you all.  I'm building a treehouse around a tree (not drilling into tree). Beam is 20 feet by 10 feet. I have six, 6x6s, on concrete footings. **I'm struggling with finalizing joist to beam connections in the middle of my beam-framing.** Here is what I have.

Idea 1 - Middle beam

On a 6x6 you have two 2x10s coming together with two more 2x10s intersecting at the middle beam. I plan to fasten with a Simpson joist hanger for two 2x10s. **Joists will run off the inner 2x10.**

[image]

Idea 2 - Notched 6x6

Here we have a notched 6x6 holding two 2x10s intersecting. **Joists will run off the inner 2x10.**

[image]

In both scenarios the joist will run across the 2x10s. I will not be building on top of these beams. The joist, which will be connected via joist hangers will run as shown. What do you all think? Which one is stronger? What connections do you recommend?

Thank you,

Dan

A Dad trying to make his kids happy

(not a contractor or engineer)

Alexandria, VA

Comment: My dad built us an awesome tree house with no tree when we were little.  5 feet up on 4"x4" risers and framed like a little 4'x4' house with shingles and everything.  We had waterfights and taco fights and learned to jump 7'-9' from the window and off the roof and roll when we hit the ground.  It was super fun.  Sometimes read books in there too.  That's a huge fort you're planning.  The water fights will be crazy.

Comment: What are the actual dimensions of the 6x6s? 10' seems like a long span but if I understand your diagram correctly should transfer the vertical load well to the posts.  The second diagram is a different type of joint but if I understand correctly you're wondering how much it might help to leave the portions of the 6x6 uncut up to the height of the top of the beams? I see one advantage that you could screw or bolt to them.  If the beams are 3" thick and the 6x6 are 5.5", the 2.5" min. pieces you could leave could be substantial and you could use them against horizontal loading or even bolt them.

Comment: this seems massively overbuilt either way, go with whatever is cheaper.